# Enterprise wsdl error: Unsupported schema type: {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType

Tags: apex, integration

currently am in working salesforce integration with sap using web services, Under Enterprise WSDL,click on “Generate Enterprise WSDL” and save it as a .wsdl file on my local machine.

That .wsdl file,Generate from WSDl under Apex classes now getting this error

**Error**:Apex Generation Failed
Unsupported schema type: {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType

1.Salesforce integrate with other system(SAP).In which WSDL file can be used.

Comment: You cannot import the salesforce enterprise wsdl back in salesforce, its for consumption in an external system which needs to make webservice calls to salesforce.

Comment: Related: [How to handle anyType of wsdl in generating apex classes](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17539/how-to-handle-anytype-of-wsdl-in-generating-apex-classes)

Answer (score 6):

The Salesforce Enterprise and Partner Web Services (WSDL's) are for consumption off platform, by languages such as Java, .Net, Ruby or PHP etc.. Generally you can perform most of the operations within them via Apex language native features such as SOQL and DML refer to the [Apex Developers guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Well , even though this API is not supposed to be used from salesforce itself, you actually can import it after some modifications, and it will work. I have done in past projects for dynamically changing schema and adding picklist values.

Answer (score 0):

Change the word "anytype" to "string" in your Wsdl.

Comment: Could you provide some kind of reference or reasoning for your recommendation please? As it stands, there doesn't seem to be any basis for your recommendation and it could easily be flagged as "Not an answer to the question" unless you can elaborate further.